# Different Behavior of an Array Shifter in Simulation

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, register-transfer-level

I am trying to debug a very strange behavior in my design. I am debugging the following piece of Systemverilog code:

```
    module ff_array
    #(
        parameter INPUT_WIDTH  = 16,
        parameter OUTPUT_WIDTH = INPUT_WIDTH*2,
        parameter ARRAY_SIZE  = 3
    )
    (
    input  logic clk,
    input  logic rst,
    input  logic signed [INPUT_WIDTH-1  : 0 ]x_in,
    output logic signed [OUTPUT_WIDTH-1 : 0 ]y_out
    );
    logic signed [INPUT_WIDTH-1 : 0 ] sh_in [ARRAY_SIZE-1:0];

    always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
        if(~rst) begin
            for (int i=0; i< ARRAY_SIZE; i++) begin
                sh_in[i] <= {OUTPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
            end
        end else begin
            sh_in[0] <= x_in;
            for (int i=1; i< ARRAY_SIZE; i++) begin
                sh_in[i] <= sh_in[i-1];
            end
        end
    end

    assign y_out   = sh_in[ARRAY_SIZE-1];
endmodule
```

The above code is a part of much bigger design but since I narrowed down the bug to the above circuit I didn't add the whole design. My expected behavior for the above code is for input to be delayed by **ARRAY_SIZE-1** times. I have a simple testbench that verifies the expected behavior which passes. The broblem starts when I use this module in a bigger design. In general the only diffenece is that the **x_in** is read from a RAM. When I compare the two waveforms (one is when the above code is the DUT and the other one is when I use it in the bigger design) I see that **x_in** in both cases behaves as expected, meaning, it arrives exactly when I expect. However for some reason, the following line behaves differently:

```
sh_in[0] <= x_in;
```

In the case when I test **ff_array** alone, the **x_in** value shifts into **sh_in[0]** exactly on the same pos edge of the clock, however, when I use it in a bigger design in which **x_in** is read from a RAM, **x_in** is shifted to the **sh_in[0]** one clock cycle **after** and not on the same clock. I really don't know the reason. I am using  xsim v2018.2 (64-bit).

Comment: What produces `x_in`? Is it synchronous to your `clk`?

Comment: yes everything is synchronous to the clk and I have only one clk in the system.

Comment: the x_in is an input stream. it is directly connected to the output of a RAM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not with the `ff_array` but a with output of the RAM or in the interconnect. Looking at simple waveforms will not help you as they do not show "delta" delays, they only show you their final value at the time step. You need to show the code that produces the output of the RAM. If it is structured similarly to your `always_ff` block here, then one would expect it to come in one clock cycle later.